# Keep columns when using do

Tags: r, dplyr

**Code**

Suppose I have the following code (I know, instead of the second `do`, I could use a simple `mutate` in this case (and skip the `rowwise()`), but that is not the point, as in my real code the second `do` is a bit more complicated and calculates a model):

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)
d <- data_frame(n = c(5, 1, 3))
e <- d %>% group_by(n) %>% 
    do(data_frame(y = rnorm(.$n), dat = list(data.frame(a = 1)))) 
e %>% rowwise() %>% do(data_frame(sum = .$y + .$n))

# Source: local data frame [9 x 1]
# Groups: <by row>

# # A tibble: 9 x 1
#         sum
# *     <dbl>
# 1 0.3735462
# 2 3.1836433
# 3 2.1643714
# 4 4.5952808
# 5 5.3295078
# 6 4.1795316
# 7 5.4874291
# 8 5.7383247
# 9 5.5757814
```

**Problem**

As you can see, the result contains only the column `sum`.

**Question**

Is there a way to **keep** the original columns from `e` **without** needing to specify them explicitly (like in `e %>% do(data_frame(n = .$n, y = .$y, dat = .$dat, sum = .$y + .$n))` in `dplyr` or do I have to use `purrrlyr::by_row`? (not that I do not like `purrrlyr`*, I was just wondering whether there is a straight forward `dplyr` way of doing it which I may have overloooked):

```
e %>% purrrlyr::by_row(function(x) x$y + x$n, .collate = "cols", .to = "sum")
```

---

*) Well, there is in fact a catch with `purrrlyr::by_row`:

```
e %>% purrrlyr::by_row(function(x) data_frame(sum = x$y + x$n, diff = x$y - x$n), 
                       .collate ="cols")
```

Will produce columns `sum1` and `diff1` which I would need to rename again to get `sum` and `diff`, which adds another line of code.

Comment: `e %>% rowwise() %>% do(data.frame(., sum = .$y + .$n))`

Comment: Well, I tried that out. But as my real `e` contains other `S3` objects this is not an option. I will adjust my question to put that into the constraints.Thanks for pointing out that my question was too simplified ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I almost never use `do`, but rather do a combination of `nest`, `mutate` and `map`.

It's a bit hard to tell how that would look in your case, as your example doesn't seem to fully specify your needs.

In the simplest case, you could specify the variables that you *do* need (if they would be lists of S3 objects, for example):

```
mutate(e, sum = map2_dbl(y, n, `+`))
```

Or, you could nest the required data then map the whole data. E.g.:

```
f <- e
f$r <- 1:nrow(e) # i.e. add some other variable, not necessarily row indices

f %>%
  ungroup() %>%                               # e was still grouped
  nest(n:dat) %>%                               # specify what you variables you need
  mutate(sum = map_dbl(data, ~.$y + .$n)) %>% # map to data, use the same formula as in do
  unnest()                                    # unnest to get original columns back
```

Both leave the original columns untouched.

For a modeling example, e.g.:

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(model = map(data, ~lm(qsec ~ hp, .)),
         coef  = map_dbl(model, ~coef(.)[2])) %>% 
  unnest(data)
```

This will give you all your original data, but with added regression coefficents per group. Before unnesting, the whole models are in your data.frame as a list column.

Comment: Very insightful +1. I never used `nest` before, and I will give it a try. I will happily accept this answer,  but before I have just 2 questions which I do not understand in your code: 1. `f$r <- 1` and then your code does not work anymore. Why? 2. where is the `model` slot in your `mtcars` example? It is there until the `unnest` command, but disappears afterwards.

Comment: Ok, I understand now why `f$r <- 1` does not work. Yet, where is the `model` slot?

Comment: Use `unnest(data, .drop = FALSE)` to keep the models (but they will be replicated). The default is `TRUE`, perhaps to avoid replicating potentially large objects many times.

Comment: Understood, that `mod` is the same for each group of `cyl`, but so is `coef`. If I understand correctly, `unnest` drops `mod` as it is a `list` while it keeps `coef` b/c it is a vector. Correct?

Comment: Yes, by default it will drop any other list columns that would need to be replicated. It will always replicate normal vector columns. See `?unnest`.

Comment: Now, having slept over it I was wondering why you would need the whole `nest` construct in the first place? This `f %>% ungroup %>% mutate(sum = map2_dbl(.$y, .$n, \`+\`))` does the trick w/o `nest`. So what is the added value?

Comment: Well yeah I showed that at the start (first line of code). Don't use `.$` there. However, sometimes you want access to many variables and you don't want to type them all out. Or, you need apply a function to a data.frame, not vectors. _"It's a bit hard to tell how that would look in your case, as your example doesn't seem to fully specify your needs."_